# tomcat 404 the requested resource is not available GeoServer Tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, geoserver

So we have an Apache Server with Tomcat7 and an installed GeoServer. 
I am connecting with SSH and i can access the server with SFTP.
The files which was installed with the Tomcat are availaible, but any file i upload with SFTP is showing me at the normal URL:

HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.64 (Ubuntu)

I have changed the ch to 777, but its not working.
I cant acces any files i upload. I uploaded an html file and an js file.
Can you help me?

Comment: how did you install geoserver? what is in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps?

Comment: We have installed it over the console.